# Azure Datafactory Lookup Activity in ForEach Failed

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am trying to insert the data ForEach iteration in ADF pipeline. inside loop, I am using LookUp activity try to insert the data in azure sql server but when we run the debug mode, i am getting failed each iteration but if I could see the inserted data in my target table. kindly help me below error.

> Failure happened on 'Source' side.
> ErrorCode=SqlInvalidDbQueryString,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The
> specified SQL Query is not valid. It could be caused by that the query
> doesn't return any data. Invalid query: 'INSERT INTO dbo.sampletable
> (id
> ,name
> ,Decription
> ,Details
> ,Status
> ,Failure
> ,date)
> VALUES('13',
> 'test',
> 'test',
> ' ',
> 'Success',
> 'NULL',
> '2023/08/22'
> )',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

[image]
[image]

my insert query in ForEach Lookup activity

```
INSERT INTO dbo.sampletable
           (id
           ,name
           ,Decription
           ,Details
           ,Status
           ,Failure
           ,date)
     VALUES('@{variables('var_id')}',
            'test',
            'test',
            '@{string(item())}',
            'Success',
            'NULL',
             '@{variables('current_date')}'
     )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please use script task to execute your insert query. The look up activity basically expects an output from your query to be present and with your insert query, there is no return value, hence the failure

Comment: you mean to say, instead of lookup, I have to use script task, how to I pass the values in my insert command, if possible, plz share some examples

Comment: Also, you can use look up activity but append the below query at the end: select '1'. There should be some value returned via look up activity

Comment: @DeveloperKE, either use script or stored procedure task (for a script you prepared in your azure sql and saved it as procedure)